# Как изменить параметры выбора choices без перезапуска

Tags: python, discord.py, discord

Мой бот завязан на базе данных которая часто обновляется.
Бот одной из команд предоставляет выбор из тем уроков (взятых из таблицы). Вроде бы работает, но если в таблицу внесены изменения во время работы бота, то без его перезапуска новые варианты выбора не появятся

сама команда:

```py
@app_commands.command()
@app_commands.default_permissions(administrator=True)
@app_commands.choices(lesson=lesson_choices())
async def create_or_update_mark(self, interaction: Interaction,
                                student: discord.Member,
                                lesson: Choice[str],
                                logiks: app_commands.Range[int, 0, 8]):
    with MarkRepository(student_id=student.id, lesson_title=lesson.value) as lr:
        lr.create_or_update(mark_dto=MarkCreateDTO(logiks=logiks))

    await interaction.response.send_message("logiks has been changed", ephemeral=True)
```

Список выбора берётся из функции `lesson_choices`

```py
def lesson_choices() -> list[Choice[str]]:
    return [
        Choice(name=lesson.title, value=lesson.title)
        for lesson in LessonRepository.get_all_lessons()
    ]
```

Вроде и понятно что декоратор определяет варианты выбора при запуска кода, но меня такое не устраивает. Есть ли способы которые помогут менять варианты выбора без перезапуска бота?

Хотел использовать `autocomplete` но там у меня даже базовых вариантов выбора не было. Возможно я не правильно реализовал автозаполнение

Команда с автозаполнением

```py
@app_commands.command()
@app_commands.default_permissions(administrator=True)
@app_commands.autocomplete(lesson=lesson_autocomplete)
async def create_or_update_mark(self, interaction: Interaction,
                                student: discord.Member,
                                lesson: str,
                                logiks: app_commands.Range[int, 0, 8]):
    with MarkRepository(student_id=student.id, lesson_title=lesson) as lr:
        lr.create_or_update(mark_dto=MarkCreateDTO(logiks=logiks))

    await interaction.response.send_message("logiks has been changed", ephemeral=True)
```

`lesson_autocomplete`:

```py
async def lesson_autocomplete(interaction: Interaction, current: str) -> list[app_commands.Choice[str]]:
    lessons = [lesson_dto.title for lesson_dto in LessonRepository.get_all_lessons()]
    print(lessons)
    return [
        app_commands.Choice(name=lesson, value=lesson)
        for lesson in lessons if current.lower() in lesson.lower()
    ]
```